# How can I Browse Eclipse Juno Source Code from within Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I tried the steps mentioned [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html) but I only get .class files imported and no source. Does anyone know a way to get it working in Juno?

Answer (score 0):

From the link:

> For other Eclipse projects you usually find a "SDK" bundle on the
>   project update site which contains the source code.

Install those *before* you do the Import of Plug-ins.